# Planar graph in graph theory

Tags: graph-theory

A graph $G$ is a simply connected planar graph, all of whose regions are bounded by $6$ edges. How do you prove the degree of vertex in $G$ is most $2$?

Comment: This is only true if the graph is finite.  The hexagonal tiling of the plane is regular of degree $3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, its not true at all,

consider this planar graph $G$ which every region in it is bounded by $6$ edges yet there is two vertices with degree $3$.

[image]

hope you see what you are looking for.

note : responding to a graph $G$ that also the outer open region is bounded by 6 edges

[image]

Comment: The outer region here is bounded by 10 edges.

Comment: i think he was concern just with closed regions and not the outer region, i will try to find a counterexample, if not i will remove my answer, thanks.

Comment: Yes, 6 edges is for closed regions.  Thank you for your example.  Can you explain it by using the dual graph of G whose each degree is 6?

Comment: if the statement were True and you are trying to proved it,may be that its useful to use dual graph in the proving process, but i posted a counterexample, so i don't know how to explain it using dual graph, but its very easy to construct many counter examples.

Answer (score 2):

What you **can** prove is:

> If $G$ is a finite, simple, connected plane graph, and all of whose regions are bounded by $6$ edges, then it has **at least one** vertex with degree $\le 2$.

This follows from [Euler's polyhedral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic):
$$ V+F = 2+E $$
When all faces are hexagonal, we have $E=3F$ and therefore
$$ V = 2+2F $$
On the other hand the sum of the degrees is $2E=6F$, which is not enough to give each of the $2+2F$ vertices degree $3$ or more.

Comment: @hardmath: Right, edited.